# Entity Framework migrations: can't convert a property to a NotMapped runtime getter

Tags: .net, entity-framework-6, visual-studio-2019

I have this in a DAL:

```
public bool MyProp { get; set; }
```

My intention is to remove that property from the db, and calculate it at runtime instead, so I've modified it like this:

```
[NotMapped]
public bool MyProp => Smthng > Something.Else;
```

However, when I run `Add-Migration -ProjectName Api.My.DAL MyClass.MyProp` from the Package Manager Console, I get this error:

> The property 'MyProp' is not a declared property on type 'MyClass'.
>   Verify that the property has not been explicitly excluded from the
>   model by using the Ignore method or NotMappedAttribute data
>   annotation. Make sure that it is a valid primitive property.

It's asking me to ensure I'm not using `NotMapped`, but I want to. And even if I remove it, the error stays exactly the same. So I no longer know what to look for.

**Disclaimer: I already searched on Google. Plenty of results, all for problems completely different from this one.** If there is something out there, it's well hidden from me.

I'm using EF6 on VS 2019 on a .NET Framework 4.7 project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was an additional check in a `Configuration` file:

```
Property(smwh => smwh.MyProp).IsRequired();
```

Removing this did the trick.